# Transferring files from ftp to local system

Tags: command-line, ftp, batch

I want to copy a file from a FTP server and save it to my local system. I want to automate this through the use of a batch file. I've been trying this for a week, but I couldn't find the solution.

This is my actual work

---

Want to copy a file named "Friday.bat" from `ftp://172.16.3.132` (with username and password):

```
@echo off
@ftp -i -s:"%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
open 172.16.3.132
mmftp
((((password entered here)))))
binary
get Friday.bat 
pause
```

Result:

---

```
ftp> @echo off
ftp> @ftp -i -s:"%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
Invalid command.
ftp> open 172.16.3.132
Connected to 172.16.3.132.
220 Welcome to ABL FTP service.
User (172.16.3.132:(none)):
331 Please specify the password.

230 Login successful.
ftp> binary
200 Switching to Binary mode.
ftp> get Friday.bat
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
550 Failed to open file.
ftp> pause
```

Finally, a file named `Friday.bat` is copied to my local system with 0 bytes and I am not able to open it.

Answer (score 0):

I would check that you are either running command prompt as an elevated user, or launching this command from a path where you have permission to write.

If this doesn't do anything, the most likely cause, and what I believe is ahppening is that your firewall is stopping you from downloading the file. Try disabling it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using PASV ([passive mode](http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html)) as the error suggests? Passive mode helps the FTP client get past firewalls and NAT devices (routers) much better as active mode tries to open a port for to you to send data (which will fail if you are behind a router) while in passive mode you are actually sucking the data down.

It's just as easy to enable passive mode as binary, and you should do it like this:

```
@echo off
@ftp -i -s:"%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
open 172.16.3.132
mmftp
((((password entered here)))))
binary
passive
get Friday.bat 
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you opposed to using a 3rd party tool like wget.exe, a Unix for Windows tool? (Download [here](http://users.ugent.be/~bpuype/wget/) or [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm))

To make it easier you can still use a script, with fast downloads of a single file or an entire site by using one line of code.

```
wget.exe --ftp-user=USERNAME --ftp-password=PASSWORD -Ofriday.bat 172.16.3.132
```

If it's not in the root directory, add `wget.exe -r` for a recursive scan of the site for a file. You can add the recursion level or span host.

Just food for thought: If you don't have to use `ftp.exe`, firewalls and other security software does not have any issues with passive – wget does all the work porting.

Answer (score 0):

Leaning on [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/294250/ftp-failed-to-open-file) I think that you have either authenticated yourself incorrectly, or lack the permissions to read the file.

Apart from that, I'd recommend you to use [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/#windows) to automate interactive applications. This tool works really well. Consider reading [this chapter](http://oreilly.com/catalog/expect/chapter/ch03.html) to get familiar with it. If that's not enough, I assure you that this is an old (stable) tool with many, many examples on the net.